# Jenkins build not failing when maven deploy task fails

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment, tomcat8

I have a Jenkins (Maven) job that builds and deploys a web service to a Tomcat 8 server.

If the deployment to the Tomcat fails the Jenkins job still finishes with success.

```
[INFO] tomcatManager status code:200, ReasonPhrase:OK
[INFO] FAIL - Deployed application at context path /dims but context failed to start
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 24.625s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 25 12:14:21 CEST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/40M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Is there a way to make the Jenkins job fail if the deployment fails?

Comment: From the small log you've posted it looks more like maven (or its plugin) problem. If you issue the same the same command from the command line do you also get this FAIL log and SUCCESS in the end?

Comment: which maven plugin are you using to deploy your ws ?

Comment: @Inforedaster I'm using tomcat-maven-plugin version 2.2.

Comment: @MirMasej If I run the command from the command line I still get the same result. The deployment fails but the build is still reported as successful.

Answer (score 0):

if you use jenkins i advise you to use jenkins deploy plugin 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in the tomcat maven plugin.

I had the same problem and use Jenkins plugin called Jenkins Text Finder. I added a post-build action called "Jenkins Text Finder" to the end of my Jenkins job. I leave the "Files" input box empty, but check the "Also search the console output" checkbox. In the regular expression inputbox I put "but context failed to start". The other two checkboxes remain unchecked.

This leads to the following output

```
[INFO] tomcatManager status code:200, ReasonPhrase:OK
[INFO] FAIL - Deployed application at context path / but context failed to start
[INFO] ----------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ----------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:23 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-29T21:15:41+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 117M/472M
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jenkins-test/core/pom.xml to cz.semanta/xf3/r8_2/xf3-r8_2.pom
[INFO] ---------------------
channel stopped
Checking console output
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jenkins-test/builds/6/log:
[INFO] FAIL - Deployed application at context path / but context failed to start
Build step 'Jenkins Text Finder' changed build result to FAILURE
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE
```

which is good enough for me.